# How to add timing while display loading image on page load

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create display loading image on page load and that is done but I am not able to specify it for a specific period of time ie I want that to load at least for 4 seconds, or remain on the screen for few seconds.

I have added CSS, jQuery, HTML as well but unable to fix timing so that it show loading at least for 10 seconds.

```
$(window).load(function () { $("#spinner").fadeOut(5000); })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#spinner").delay(10000).fadeOut(5000);
});
```

This will delay for 10 seconds and then fade.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cDyX6/

Comment: no even this thing is not working ..i dont no whats wrong i have tried all possible ways..well thanks

Comment: @user3632406 Have you updated to using $(document).ready() instead of $(window).load()? And does the js fiddle link I provided work for you (just to check if its a browser issue)? What does happen? The delay() should work, I'm pretty sure it's what you need.

Comment: @user3632406 what sorted it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`$(document).ready(function() { }`** method instead of this **`$(window).load(function ()`** method.

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#spinner").fadeOut('slow');
});
```

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7Zwk/)**</kbd>

---

#### $(document).ready()

> One time initialize.

#### $(window).load(function ()

> initialize multiple time for updating contents. and unsuitable for initialize one time.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach with a timer.

Probably unnecessarily complex compared to the other answers - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jd2f/).

CSS

```
$('.spinnerdiv').show();
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
                                       $('.spinnerdiv').hide(1000);
                                       }, 4000,
                                       function(){
                                                  clearInterval( interval );
                                                  });
```